# Python: how to create a submatrix discretizing a circle?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, grid, shapes

In a 2D square grid (matrix) full of `zeros`, I need to create a submatrix full of `ones`, with the shape of this submatrix being as close as possible to a circle. I know a circle cannot be precisely represented when you work with cells or pixels, therefore I aim at a discretized circle.

The best thing I could come up with was this code, which produces **square submatrices** (the blue square in the image below):

```
from __future__ import division 
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import random
import os
import math

n=101 #Grid size
empty_lattice=numpy.zeros((n,n)) #The empty 2D grid
x=int(numpy.random.uniform(0,n-1)) #X coord. top left corner
y=int(numpy.random.uniform(0,n-1)) #Y coord. top left corner
side=int(numpy.random.uniform(15,n)) #Side of the square approximating the circle
max_y=n-y #Checks the distance between the y of the submatrix origin and the matrix vertical boundary
max_x=n-x #Checks the distance between the x of the submatrix origin and the matrix horizontal boundary
max_width=0 #Initializes a maximum width for the loading submatrix
if max_y<max_x: #This assigns the minimum value between max_y and max_x to max_width, so that the submatrix is always a square
    max_width=max_y
else:
    max_width=max_x     
if side>max_width:
    for i in range(0,max_width):
        for j in range(0, max_width):
            empty_lattice[x+i][y+j]=1
else:
    for i in range(0, side):
        for j in range(0, side):
            empty_lattice[x+i][y+j]=1
```

Now, visually this translates into the following image, but as you know there is a noticeable difference between the blue square and the inscribed circle in terms of area:
[image]

**My question:** how could I amend my code in order to be able to "smooth" the corners of my squares so that something which resembles a circle appears?

**EDIT**

The circles should be drawn even if they do not entirely reside within the grid boundaries (look at the image).

Comment: Take a look at the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Comment: Will this allow me to produce truncated circles? These appear when the circle center is either on the boundaries or past them, but there is still room for drawing a section of the circle.

Comment: Maybe read at least the Contents parts of the article he linked, that would answer your question. You can also make a bigger grid, draw complete circles and truncate afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function fills in a circle of 1s that looks pretty good.

```
def fill_cell(cell, corner, rad):
    m, n = cell.shape
    ctr = corner[0]+m/2, corner[1]+n/2
    x = np.arange(m) - ctr[0]
    y = np.arange(n) - ctr[1]
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, order='ij')  # could try order='xy'
    Z = ((X**2 + Y**2)<= rad**2).astype(cell.dtype)
    return Z
empty_lattice[:] = fill_cell(empty_lattice, (x,y),side/2)
```

Position in `empty_lattice` is not right - because of a difference in how you are defining the `x,y` coordinates and my assumptions, but I think you can sort that out.

Radius looks good, though it might be off by an integer.

To fill in multiple circles, you could iterate over the `x,y` values, and 
assign lattice values for a slice (view)

```
xyslice = slice(x,15), slice(y,15)
empty_lattice[xyslice] = fill_cell(empty_lattice[xyslice],...)
```

For overlapping circles I'd look into some sort of logical assignment

```
empty_lattice[xyslice] |= fill_cell(...)
```